# Is there a polyurethane product that works both indoors and outdoors on concrete and wood?

Tags: concrete, wood, stairs, polyurethane

I need to seal some stairs indoors and also an outdoor concrete slab that was recently painted. But I would refer to buy a single gallon to get it all done.  Oil vs water and which product should I get?  ... or do I need 2 separate ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For outdoor use you want a finish with good UV resistance and some elasticity. A spar varnish is the usual solution.

You can certainly use a spar varnish inside as well, but it won't be as durable against mechanical wear as a non-spar varnish would be, and may not be as clear.

You can use an indoor varnish outside to, if you're willing to refinish much more often. It won't be as happy with either sunlight or wide temperature swings.

Pick your tradeoffs. Or get two different products in smaller cans, which is what I'd do.

Oil vs water: oil-based is more durable but harder to work with/clean up after and has a yellow tint. Water-based is clear (or slightly foggy if you get flat rather than glossy) and easier to work with and clean up.